# EntityFramework 6.1 cannot connect

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class library I have been using for over a year that has recently stopped working after upgrading to EF 6.1.

I have tried various methods for passing in the connect string to my Context class constructor but while it seems to correctly pass the string I invariably receive:

'(((System.Data.Entity.DbContext)(context)).Database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

and the connection state stays closed.

Here is my AppConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My test class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SVMIC.IMS.Entity.IMSClaim
{
    public class Context:DbContext
    {
        static Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
        }

        public Context():base("MyContext")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and my test app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SVMIC.IMS.Entity.IMSClaim;

namespace TestApp
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      Context context = new Context();

    }
  }
}
```

The database server is SQL Server 2008 R2.

I assume it is something simple changed in 6.1 and I am just missing it, but I am totally stumped.

Comment: your connection string appears to be the issue / problem this is what my connection string looks like for example
`<add name="DataHubDevEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEDM.csdl|res://*/MyEDM.ssdl|res://*/MyEDM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DALVS291;initial catalog=DataHub_Dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>`

Comment: @DJKRAZE Your connection string looks like that because you use DB first. This person appears to be using code first.

Comment: That's true as well.. perhaps it would be more advisable for the OP to show more code especially in the regards of how they are connecting to the DB

Comment: I use code first, DBContext, only and have been using this connect string for over a year without a problem.

Comment: That is how I am connecting to the database. I have no additional code as I made this sample up to demonstrate the problem and simplify the example.

Comment: can you show the method of how you are connecting? did you happen to upgrade from EF 5.x to EF 6.1 recently..?

Comment: The code above is complete and results in the same error as my main project. Yes, I upgraded to 6.1 and at first it was fine, but then I made a small code change to my class and it started failing, rolling back the change made no difference.

Comment: @DJKRAZE There is no "method" to connect, it happens during EF operations behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes.. but the first point of failure is when I set the connection string. it returns the exception show above and then all that follows fails because the connection does not open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have resolved the issue.

In frustration at not being able to fix the issue with 6.1, nothing I did made any difference to the result, and even building and stepping through the EF source accomplished little so I rolled back to EF 5.0 and rebuilt my code.

EF 5 immediately returned an error message identifying an issue in the schema definition, a view added by another developer that referenced system views was confusing my template, I fixed the issue and was back working in a matter of minutes.

The lesson learned here was, EF 6 needs some serious work on its error handling, as just returning a generic exception error left me chasing off in every direction, while the error message from EF 5 pointed me directly at the issue.

Comment: I just had the same problem... for real this last 2 hours I was suffering... but I solved it basically setting the code into a "try/catch", and the catch gave me the literal exception. Btw, I guess this happens because is an error in an async method, well at least it was my case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments what appears to have happened is:

- The original EF Upgrade did not work, so you were still running on the old EF
- When you made the code change, the rebuild triggered that you would use the New EF
- But the New EF dll's are not available, so you get the error.

Check you config: the EF Version is 6.0 not 6.1, also the Public key token is the same as for .net 2.0.

Comment: The upgrade not working is possible, the upgrade process for EF via NuGet is very unreliable, but I confirmed at the time the the DLL's being referenced were indeed the new version. But the code you see above is from a new desktop setup and a brand new sample project where the only EF installed into the solution was EF 6.1 and the issue persists. I did not add the EF section line, it did that itself when I added 6.1 to the solution, so if it should be something else I have no idea what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information on this error

I was configuring Repository and Unit of Work Design Pattern with EF 6.1 with a simple test database named as "School"

It had following 3 tables

BookMaster

Library and

Student

I had created their respective Entity classes, Configurations classes, Repository classes and also created DB Sets in Entities class.

After few days I had created one more table whose above mentioned classes and DbSets were not created.

What I found is providing connectionstring name in base() constructor parameter was giving me following error

> '(context.Database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type >'System.InvalidOperationException' entity framework 6.1

However if I pass complete connection string as a parameter to base() method then it was working.

After some Trial and Error I deleted the 4th table that was created and It worked like a dream. So may be it is necessary to utilize all the tables and create the above mentioned classes and DbSets which may resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are working local MDF file, the update the folder path of MDF file in App.config/ Web.config
else copy the dbmx App.cofig connectionStrings  and paste to your project App.config/Web.config file.